# Parse out key:values in dictionary nested in MRSS feed using Python Feedparser

Tags: python, list, dictionary, feedparser

I've looked through the Python feedparser documentation and done enough Googling, but not finding any example feeds that look like what I'm working with:

http://smrss.neulion.com/u/nhl/mrss/sights-and-sounds/vod.xml

What I'm trying to access is the mp4 URLs in the media:group --> media:content element in each item in the feed.

Here's my code so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import feedparser

d = feedparser.parse('http://smrss.neulion.com/u/nhl/mrss/sights-and-sounds/vod.xml')

for index,item in enumerate(d.entries):
    if index >= 4:
        print item.title
        print item.media_content
        print item.summary
```

What prints out to Terminal for item.media_content is:

```
[{'duration': u'150', 'url': u'http://smrss.neulion.com/spmrss/s/nhl/vod/flv/2015/04/19/811204_20150418_PIT_NYR_WIRELESS_1800_sd.mp4', 'type': u'video_sd.mp4'}]
```

This is a dictionary inside of a list, yes? What would be the best way to iterate through this dictionary in my for loop so I can extract the value at the 'url' key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if item.media_content is always a list with one dictionary, just do this:

```
for key, val in item.media_content[0].iteritems():
    print key, val
```

Comment: Thank you very much for breaking that down! I was missing the [0] — I'm assuming we need to tell Python which index the list is at, even if there's only one media_content list per item in the feed?

Comment: You're welcome :-) Indeed, you first tell Python to get the first item of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) :

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://smrss.neulion.com/u/nhl/mrss/sights-and-sounds/vod.xml"
vod = urllib.urlopen(url)



In [1752]: [i['url'] for i in soup.findAll('media:content') if i.has_attr('url')]
Out[1752]: 
['http://smrss.neulion.com/spmrss/s/nhl/vod/flv/2015/04/30/817293_C150008B_20150428_ROUND_ONE_WIRELESS_RECAP_SHORT_5000_sd.mp4',
 'http://smrss.neulion.com/spmrss/s/nhl/vod/flv/2015/04/28/816995_20150427_NHL_Playoff_Access_NYI_WSH_GM7_5000_sd.mp4',
 'http://smrss.neulion.com/spmrss/s/nhl/vod/flv/2015/04/26/816230_20150426_WIRELESS_RECAP_5000_sd.mp4',
 'http://smrss.neulion.com/spmrss/s/nhl/vod/flv/2015/04/25/815823_20150425_WIRELESS_GM5_OTT_5000_sd.mp4',
```